# Entity Framework and Generics for bulk methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-5

I have migrated an application from Linq To Sql to Entity Framework.

We use this application to synchronize registries between two sql servers.

When we were using Link to sql, we could use some bulk operations like

the following snippet:

```
List<MyTable> listaMyTable = (from p in db1_context.MyTable
                                                select p).ToList();

db1_context.MyTable.InsertAllOnSubmit(listaMyTable );
```

That allowed us to bulk insert registers from databaseContext1 to databaseContext2

Once I have migrated the application to Entity Framework 5 I see that there are no
bulk operations available, so I decided to make some generic methods like this:

```
 public static int  InsertAllOnSubmit<T>(this ObjectContext db, List<T> newentities) where T : EntityObject
        {
            var objectSet = db.CreateObjectSet<T>();
            newentities.ForEach(x => objectSet.AddObject(x));
            int inserted = db.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);
            return inserted;
        }  

        public static int DeleteAllOnSubmit<T>(this ObjectContext db, List<T> deleteEntities) where T : EntityObject
        {
            var DelSet = db.CreateObjectSet<T>();
            deleteEntities.ForEach(x => DelSet.DeleteObject(x));
            int deleted= db.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);
            return deleted;
        }
```

So I can do almost the same using:

```
//Using AsNoTracking to disable tracking between contexts
 List<MyTable> listaMyTable = (from p in db1_context.MyTable.AsNoTracking()
                                                    select p).ToList();
 db2_context.InsertAllOnSubmit(listamyTable);
```

I would like to know if they are any way to make through generics, the same thing
I have done but loading something like a `List<List<T>>` so I can iterate all tables and make bulk operations.

It would be something like

```
EntitiesList.add(Entity);
EntitiesList.add(Entity2);
EntitiesList.add(Entity3);
```

And make a generic method who iterates through entities and create the ObjectSet for every type in list.

So I can the method like

```
 dbContext.InsertAllEntities(EntitiesList);
```

I dont know If I made myself clear. If you need more information just ask.

Comment: You want to create a method that loads all data from all tables? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Hmm, That wouldn't fit in a List<List<T>> unless you use your base type for T but then that list would be useless since you can't access your properties

Comment: Yeah, That is why I don't know how to achieve this. No clue how can I do it :/

Comment: I don't see how can this be done through generics since types won't match. From a 2min thinking the only way to do this is have a List<List<object>> then use reflection to determine type and access properties but that would be the worst thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dynamic` data type to resolve the type of `T` for each `IList<>` at runtime.

```
public static void InsertAllListsOnSubmit(
    this ObjectContext db, IList<IList<object>> lists)
{
    foreach (IList<object> list in lists)
    {
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            dynamic instance = list[0];
            db.InsertAllOnSubmit(instance, list);
        }
    }
}
```

and change your method signature to take a dummy instance of T

```
public static int  InsertAllOnSubmit<T>(
    this ObjectContext db, T instance, IList<T> newentities)
    where T : EntityObject
{
    var objectSet = db.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    newentities.ForEach(x => objectSet.AddObject(x));
    int inserted = db.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);
    return inserted;
}
```